# Asus AC53 nano install

Tags: networking, drivers, asus

i am currently running one of your flavors named Kubuntu 18.04 bionic beaver. Since i installed it on my machine i been having issues with my Asus AC53 nano wireless to recognize the OS under the networking settings. the question would there be driver out there for me to use to recognize and install wireless adapter? need whelp in this. As of now i been using the belkin 300 mbps as my other device for wireless communication but even with that i been having problems communicating to my router need help please thank you

Comment: Hi Warhog1, and welcome to askUbuntu!  please plug in your wireless usb device and add the output of following commands to your post: `lshw -C network` , `nmcli device show` and `lsusb` .

Comment: ok i will when i get home from work. so do i have to use the terminal right to input commands?

Comment: yes, you have to open a terminal and type in these commands.

Comment: ok when i get home i will do it an hope it will work. I been using this os quite a while but love it.

Comment: Sometimes i get crashes were the panel or the OS loses it time in processing. also it has a way restarting with no apparent reason.